# Swift returns error 'Binary operator == cannot be applied to two EKSourceType operands'

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I have code like this in Xcode 6.3:

```
let store = EKEventStore()

for source in store.sources() {
    let st: EKSourceType = source.sourceType!
    if st == EKSourceTypeLocal {
        localSource = source;
    }
}
```

The fifth line (if st..) gives the complier error: 'Binary operator == cannot be applied to two EKSourceType operands'

How can I check if the source is local or not (in Swift) and get this to compile?

Comment: There’s no need to force-unwrap `source.sourceType`, it’s already an implicitly unwrapped optional so your code will crash nicely if it’s ever `nil` without a helping hand :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Like this:

```
if st.value == EKSourceTypeLocal.value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not direct compare any class or structure with static value so you always use its value or need an instance of class or structure to compare.

so you can use as below to compare

```
    for source in store.sources() {
    let st: EKSourceType = source.sourceType!
    if st == EKSourceTypeLocal.value {
        localSource = source;
    }
}
```